# How to make Qt Creator use variables in the builddir path, so I can easily rename project?

Tags: qt, build, path, qt-creator, project

In Qt Creator, in `Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> General -> Build and Run -> Default build directory` I have this value:

> ../build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}

This works but on project creation the variables in that string get replaced with their values, which means that if I later rename the project, I need to go through all of [Debug, Profile, Release] modes and manually change the builddir's path so it reflects the new project name.

**So I want:**

- A way to use variables like `%{CurrentProject:Name}` in the project settings
- (less important) A way to have Qt Creator automatically put references to such variables in the project settings on project creation, so I don't have to adjust them on project creation
- Alternatively: Some other pain-free way to rename my project without having to update so many places

Note: I could remove the project-name part from the builddir template, and put the builddir in "`.`" (project dir) rather than in "`..`" (parent of project dir), that way it would work and there would be no name collisions (MS Visual Studio does it this way), but unfortunately [qmake has a limitation](https://forum.qt.io/topic/4001/what-is-the-the-build-directory-needs-to-be-at-the-same-level-as-the-source-directory-warning/6) (see tobias.hunger's post) that makes it sometimes break unless the project dir is at "the same level" as the builddir.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement this feature yourself. This happens so rarely that until now nobody really needed it. A workaround, if your build/run environment isn't customized, is to remove all kits from the project and re-add the desired kits. It will then create build folders using appropriate names.

But it seems like much ado about nothing: Qt Creator's build folder names might as well be random strings, you should not need to manually refer to them. For product deployment, you'd be using some sort of a CI system, or a manually invoked build script that stages the deliverable(s) (e.g. installer or disk image) where they belong.